# z-index second tier dropdown behind nav wrapper

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, z-index

Is it possible to z-index the a menu second tier dropdown behind a main nav wrapper

here's my example so far
http://cdpn.io/qawIJ

I can't see what i'm missing

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `z-index` property from everything but your `.dropdown` class (leaving it as `z-index: -1`).

[Here's a working demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IjCbx).